# What settings are available in FireDAC that affect performance when connecting to MSSQL using C++ Builder XE8

Tags: sql-server, c++builder, firedac

I am using **XE8**, **Windows 7, 8, 8.1** with a traditional **client-server setup** using `FireDAC`, **C++ Builder XE8**, **MSSQL native client 11**.

When developing this solution and currently in-house performance is stellar.  When deploying users have different experiences.  Some are totally fine, performance is adequate or great.

Some clients report unbearable slowness.  We found a client with `ODBC` tracing enabled which was huge and solved the slowness issues for that client.

In general the `DBX` (prior version) code we upgraded from was faster at executing queries than `FireDAC`.

I have looked at any and all configuration options but cannot find out what magic setting is causing some users to experience this slowness.  `FireDAC` is the premium data access components for Embarcadero technologies but I am having trouble convincing management and end users that it is up to the job.

Here is my startup:

```c++
FDManager()->Active = true;
FDManager()->ResourceOptions->DirectExecute = true;

FDManager()->FetchOptions->Unidirectional = true;
FDManager()->FetchOptions->RowsetSize = 1000;
FDManager()->FetchOptions->Mode = fmOnDemand;
FDManager()->FetchOptions->Items = TFDFetchItems() << fiBlobs << fiDetails;
FDManager()->FetchOptions->AutoFetchAll = afAll;
FDManager()->FetchOptions->Mode = fmAll;

FDManager()->UpdateOptions->ReadOnly = true;
FDManager()->UpdateOptions->RequestLive = false;

// make DB connections here
```

Need some advice on best practices for performance.

Comment: First off, are you sure you are using native client, not ODBC driver? And next depends on what you fetch. `Unidirectional` can reduce memory (_visited_ records are discarded), `RowsetSize` is configured automatically (I would not modify it), `Items` `fiDetails` applies to master-detail, `fiBlobs` fetches blob value for each record even if it's not read (this may be _heavy_), `Mode` `fmAll` fetches all records (that can be slow on huge resultsets, if your app. displays data in a grid, it's not efficient, if you really want the whole resultset _at once_, it can be useful).

Comment: In any case, there is no ultimate answer so long you don't describe what do you want to do with the data. Are you going to display them in a grid, or process the whole resultset at once (and if so, is it enough a forward cursor)? Are you fetching BLOB fields with another fields without reading them? Do you want to save memory and would be enough for you having forward cursor?